# How to add a part of an image to a Button in HTML

Tags: html, css

I've a big image and I'd like to add a part of that image to a button. I've a css class that defines the left and top where the little part of the whole image I want is located. Let's say

```
.image
{
  left: -20;
  top: -200px;
}
```

I've defined another class that describes the place where I want to put this part of the image.

```
.image16x16
{
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  height:16px;
  width:16px;
}
```

Now I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<button class='image16x16' type='button'><img class='image' src='image.png'/></button>
```

But the image is moved outside the area reserved. However, if I change the button to be a simple div or input, the image is place correctly.

```
<div class='image16x16' type='button'><img class='image' src='image.png'/></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/) on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/).

#### CSS

```
div.sprite
{
    /*height and width of the sprites*/
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url("sprites.png");
    display: inline-block;
}
div.delete
{
    /*Pixel offsets within the image for a red cross*/
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
div.confirm
{
    /*Pixel offsets within the image for a green tick*/
    background-position: 0x -16px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<button>
    <div class="sprite delete"></div>
    Delete
</button>
<button>
    <div class="sprite confirm"></div>
    Confirm
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally understand your issue, but since a DIV works as you expect perhaps you just need to add this css:

```
button { display: block; }
```

Answer (score -1):

`left` and `top` have no meaning without a position other than `static`!

```
.image
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -20;
    top: -200px;
}
```

Also, there's no need to apply `class="image"` to your `<img>` tag. Just use this:

```
.image16x16 img
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -20;
    top: -200px;
}
```

Comment: "left and top have no meaning without a position other than static!" This is a false statement. A position of absolute will also give meaning to left and top.

Comment: You're misreading it. Eric said a position *other than* static. I.e. relative, absolute or fixed. And those are the 3 values for which left/top/right/bottom have meaning.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: `left` and `top` have no meaning with a position of `static`. Sorry for the slightly ambiguous statement.